# how to interrupt a stuck ssh connection

Tags: ssh

Oooops i just typed "ip link set eth0 down" while i was sshed into a server. that ssh session is now stuck for the timeout. Is there a key I can press to kill the ssh session with out waiting for the timeout?

Comment: Depends on which client you're using. Are you using Putty? Or a *nix client?

Comment: it is a Linux client

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Assuming you're on some kind of Unix/Linux/OS X and running 'ssh' from a terminal;

```
<enter> ~.
```

(also ~? will show you lots of other sometimes helpful keys)

Comment: Finally, something that actually works. I'd +10 if I could.

Comment: awesome tip. just to clarify: <enter> can also be <return>